# vagrant up throws The following command responded with a non-zero exit status

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, vagrant

I am getting the following error, during the execution of vagrant up:

```
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mount -o vers=3,udp 192.168.33.1:/Users/freid/www/projects /vagrant

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

mount.nfs: requested NFS version or transport protocol is not supported
```

My Vagrant file looks like:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
    v.name = "projects"
    v.customize [
        "modifyvm", :id,
        "--name", "projects",
        "--memory", 2048,
        "--natdnshostresolver1", "on",
        "--cpus", 1,
    ]
end

config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.71"
config.ssh.forward_agent = true

config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"   
end
```

I have run vagrant box update along with updating my version of vagrant to the latest v1.9.5

I'm trying to set this up as a local development environment on my mac machine, but what am I doing wrong, any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Either the server you try to mount from don't support NFS vers=3 or it don't support UDP .. or the proto has to be `udp` - that is, no capital letters.

Comment: Thanks @SorenA i'm running this on my mac machine which I belive supports NFS v3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding 127.0.0.1 localhost to the /etc/hosts file. The issue seems to have gone away.